# How to keep user logged in after logging in to his account forever using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

hey i tried so many ways and research about it too much but still i am facing this error so can someone pls tell me how to keep user logged in after logging in  to his account forever using firebase

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Pressable,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { firebase } from "../../firebase";

import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Validator from "email-validator";

const LoginForm = ({ navigation }) => {
  const LoginFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required("An email is required"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required()
      .min(6, "Your password has to have at least 6 characters"),
  });

  const onLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log("Firebase Login Successfully" + email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          onLogin(values.email, values.password);
        }}
        validationSchema={LoginFormSchema}
        validateOnMount={true}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, isValid }) => (
          <>
            <View
              style={[
                styles.inputField,
                {
                  borderColor:
                    values.email.length < 1 || Validator.validate(values.email)
                      ? "#ccc"
                      : "red",
                },
              ]}
            >
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Phone Number, username or email"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                textContentType="emailAddress"
                autoFocus={true}
                onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                onBlur={handleBlur("email")}
                value={values.email}
              />
            </View>
            <View
              style={[
                styles.inputField,
                {
                  borderColor:
                    1 > values.password.length || values.password.length >= 6
                      ? "#ccc"
                      : "red",
                },
              ]}
            >
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                textContentType="password"
                onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
                onBlur={handleBlur("password")}
                value={values.password}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", marginBottom: 30 }}>
              {/* <Text style={{ color: "#68B0F5" }}>Forgot Password?</Text> */}
            </View>
            <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Pressable
                titleSize={20}
                style={styles.button(isValid)}
                disabled={!isValid}
                onPress={handleSubmit}
              >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log In</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.signupContainer}>
              <Text>Don't have an account?</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push("SignupScreen")}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#68B0F5" }}>Sign Up</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    marginTop: 80,
  },
  inputField: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: "#FAFAFA",
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  button: (isValid) => ({
    backgroundColor: isValid ? "#DC143C" : "#f56991",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    minHeight: 42,
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: "60%",
  }),
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  signupContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
  },
});

export default LoginForm;
```

and i am creating a Instagram clone with the help of this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbixZZDjrdU&t=390s

Comment: By default, the user does stay logged in forever. What is not working in this case?

Comment: no it is not working  when i login to my app and after refresh it or reopen it logged me out

Comment: you can use Asyncstorage. when user login you add that credential to asyncstorage. and on splash screen you can add condition if asyncstorage is not empty then move to home otherwise move to login page

Comment: thank you Talha Akbar sir but i am new at this so can you please tell me how to implement this pls pls

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your user again for the password and re-authendicate him with:

```js
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
  const user = firebase.auth.currentUser;
  if (user) reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential);
```

If the above doesn't work, use your login function.

It is not suggested though to save user's password in AsyncStorage and re-use it to re-log him in an every refresh.

Comment: no it doesn't work pls help me

Comment: use again your login function

Comment: Another way would be to login/signup the user with using the REST API that returns a token and a refresh token. So on each app refresh you use the refresh token to get a new token. Then you don't need user password.

Comment: To use Firebase REST API, you may attend [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-native-the-practical-guide/learn/lecture/13914812#questions) and then in lecture 228 there is [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-native-the-practical-guide/learn/lecture/13914812#questions/9136552) answer on how to keep user logged in forever.

Comment: no it's still not working